# Can't create venv in docker jupyter image (permissions)

Tags: python, docker, permissions, python-venv

When trying to docker build from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

... I receive the following error:

```
Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/venv'
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It works fine with other parent images.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Since my Dockerfile doesn't contain a `USER ...` line, the `RUN` line which tries to create the venv is operating as `root` user isn't it?

I've tried the usual things like including a `RUN chown appuser /opt` higher up in the Dockerfile without success.

Comment: Since this is a docker instance, do you really need or want an environment?

Comment: Not necessarily, I have seen it debated though

Comment: You get whatever `USER` is in the base image, which may not necessarily be root.

Comment: Oh thanks @DavidMaze, I believed it was root.